# Latency for SQLite update propagation across iCloud

Tags: sqlite, ios5, icloud, transaction-log

I've build a library-style SQLite iOS app using the code in the Recipes sample app, and it works - updates on one device are (eventually) reliably propagated to all other devices running the same app. I've been testing it with multiple events per hour all day long, and all the log transactions do get to every device. However, the time for the updates to propagate is highly variable. If I bring the app up and let it sit, it could be a relatively long time before the cloud sends update transactions to the app, and so what's on-screen remains old data for that same long time. Worse, there's no indication the data is out of date.

If I cause the app to post a change to the cloud, though, updates ***from*** the cloud propagate down relatively soon. That suggests that I could put in a hack that periodically posts pointless changes to the database, but even then I won't know if I've received all the changes.

First question: Do methods that will force transactions to propagate exist? [a This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184264/icloud-update-policy-on-coredata-in-development-and-production-mode) suggests not.

Second question: Is there a way to detect if the local database is out of date? I don't want to tickle the cloud copy incessantly, but doing so now and then until the database is current might not be such a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

1) if you find such methods, please let me know.

2) same stuff here. I didn't even find any reliable way to detect whether the currently running instance of the iCloud app is not the first instance i.e. other instances have already sent updates to the iCloud until the first push received (which can take some unknown time)

Comment: As an experiment, I added code to my app that used key-value cloud posting to track when content categories in my database had been updated, and by what UUID, and then used that date stamp to color items in the UI that represented out-of-date transactions.

Comment: The experiment didn't work, in that never found a case where the key-value data updated sooner than the actual core data transactions. My algorithm for recording key-value dates is such that the datestamp would always be updated after the data transaction if they're serialized in time or even in the same log. That correlated behavior, although entirely plausible, is not something I've seen explicitly documented.